# Sparse Sampled Softmax Tensorflow

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

How would you transform `tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` to use a **sampled softmax** instead of a regular softmax ?

I have a sequence to sequence model with a large target vocabulary (500K words), and it triggers OOM errors.

The input to the softmax function looks like: `[batch, max_time_steps, 512]`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, solved it using:

```
        labels = tf.reshape(labels, [-1, 1])
        loss = tf.nn.sampled_softmax_loss(
            weights=self.W_softmax,
            biases=self.b_softmax,
            labels=labels,
            inputs=logits,
            num_sampled=20,
            num_true=1,
            num_classes=20000,
            partition_strategy="div")
```

The key for me was to set the `num_sampled=20` fairly low, 512 was too much to fit in my GPU memory (8GB).